# vector as function's input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i'd like to Write
a function that receives a 2x1 matrix cointaining the x and y.(no scalar inputs)
 is it possible?
I tried as below:

```
function [d] = dist(A,B)

d=sqrt(((A(1)-B(1))^2+(A(2)-B(2))^2));
end
```

A and B are 2*1 matrices .
how to put vector as function's input??

Comment: Your code looks OK. Is it not working for you? Not sure I understand your question. How are you calling your function `dist`?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, perhaps you could edit your question and add a small numerical example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass two vectors (since you have A and B each having two elements) as a single parameter, you can either create a 2x2 matrix or a 4x1 vector to pass in. Or you can decide to pass in a cell array (which gives you a bit more flexibility).  Example:

```
A = [1 2];
B = [4 5];

C = [A; B];

d = myDistance(C);

function m = myDistance(x)
  dxy = diff(x); % do both x(2,1) - x(1,1) and x(2,2) - x(1,2) in one operation
  m = sqrt(sum(dxy.^2));
```

Alternatively, passing `A` and `B` as two separate parameters (which makes a lot of sense from readability) should work in the way you described in your question...

Answer (score 1):

I have a different interpretation of your question, I think you're asking how to make your function output all the distances for two lists of (x,y) coords? If so then like this:

```
function [d] = Dist(A,B)
    d=sqrt(((A(:,1)-B(:,1)).^2+(A(:,2)-B(:,2)).^2));
end
```

So you need to change your `^` from a matrix operation to an elementwise vector operation `.^` and then you need to access the first column but ALL the rows i.e. `(1,:)`

e.g.

```
A = [0,0;
     0,1;
     1,1]
B = [1,1;
     1,1;
     1,1]

Dist(A,B)

ans =

   1.41421
   1.00000
   0.00000
```

By the way you could neaten up this function like this and still get the same result:

```
function [d] = Dist(A,B)
    d=sqrt(sum((A-B).^2,2));
end
```

Comment: +1 for the compact second formulation which will still work when `A` and `B` are matrices. Agree that the question was open to multiple interpretations, and your answer is useful for the alternative interpretation.